# Factorial using do - while loop. The num1 variable is getting equal to zero but the condition of the while is num1>=1. how does this works?

Tags: java, do-while, factorial

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a number ") ;

int num = scan.nextInt();

int num1 = num;
do {
      num1--;  
      num = num * num1; 
} while (num1 >= 1);

System.out.println(num);
```

Why is the result zero, since condition is if num1 is greater than or equal than 1?

Comment: The loop exits when `num1` is no longer >= 1, which happens when it's equal to 0.

Comment: You are using a `do - while` loop. The loop invariant must be `false` for the loop to end, and in the loop body you subtract one from `num1` (**terrible** variable names by the way) on each iteration. Thus after **exactly** `num` (just ***terrible*** variable names) iterations `num1` must be `0`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thanks. btw I'm just practicing how to code that's why I came up with those lame variable names

Comment: It's okay, with short variable names like `a`, `b`, `i`, `j` you know where you stand. But with `num` and `num1` you can never quite tell. *"I hate these filthy Neutrals, Kif. With enemies you know where they stand but with Neutrals, who knows? It sickens me."* -- Zap Brannigan

Answer (score 2):

As it's a do while loop and you are checking for num1 >=1 the loop exexutes value num1=1 ,
 and num1-- results to num1 =0 , thus resulting whole factorial to be zero :

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number ") ;

int num=scan.nextInt();
int num1 = num ;
  do{
     num1--;

  num= num * num1; 



}while(num1>=2);   // changed to 2
 System.out.println(num);
 }
```